# Is a lightlike vector potential (A²=0) a valid and/or useful choice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge

I know [most common choices to fix the gauge of a vector potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing), but I wonder if there are no other choices possible.

As a concrete example inspired by the Schrödinger equation with magnetic field, I would suggest $\vec{A}^2=0$ so that the quadratic term $\frac{e^2 \vec{A}^2}{2m}$ in the minimally coupled Schrödinger equation drops out, instead of the more customary $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = 0$ so that another term "disappears".

Is this a correct/useful gauge choice? Are there any previous applications?

Answer (score 3):

There is a confusion between 3D space and 4D spacetime, and between relativistic and non-relativistic physics, implicit in the question.

The title talks about a "lightlike" vector. That should obey
$$A_\mu A^\mu = 0$$
and is indeed generally "one" condition on the four-vector, so it would replace the Lorenz gauge.

However, the question talks about
$$ \vec A^2 = 0 $$
which looks like an equation for the 3-vector. Obviously, this "gauge condition" is no good because it would require $\vec A=(0,0,0)$ for all three spatial components and no magnetic fields would be allowed at all.

The motivation in the question talks about the cancellation of the term $\vec A^2$ in Schrödinger's equation. But as long as we talk about the electron, Schrödinger's equation is non-relativistic and the squared term is indeed just the square of the spatial components, as the symbols actually say, so they don't yield an acceptable gauge choice.

Relativistically, the electron is described by the Dirac equation which contains at most linear terms in $\vec A_\mu$ (multiplied by $\gamma^\mu$).

So there's no viable choice of this kind that would simplify a non-relativistic equation or the relativistic equation for the fermions. And there's no viable choice that would include the spatial components i.e. vector potential only.

The original 4D choice, $A_\mu A^\mu=0$, is OK except for its being non-smooth (and allowing many ways how to extend the gauge potential) whenever we approach the point with $A_\mu=(0,0,0,0)$. And when we are far from $(0,0,0,0)$, the quadratic equation may be approximated by a linear one, anyway. If $A_0^\mu$ is a null vector (with large enough coordinates) that obeys the condition, the condition
$$ (A_0^\mu +\Delta A^\mu) (A_{0\mu} + \Delta A_\mu) = 0$$
may be expanded to yield simply
$$A_0^\mu \cdot \Delta A_mu = 0$$
when we neglect the subleading, quadratic part in $\Delta A$. This linear equation above is nothing else than the light-cone gauge, equivalent to $A_0+A_z=0$ in some coordinates.

Similarly, if your gauge condition were
$$A_\mu A^\mu = \pm c^2$$
demanding that $A$ is a spacelike or timelike vector of a fixed length (in units of mass), for large enough $A$, the equation would reduce to the usual $A_0=0$ temporal gauge or $A_z=0$ axial (?) gauge in some coordinates.

The nonlinear generalization of the light cone gauge isn't terribly useful because the vacuum Maxwell equations are linear and we want to exploit the linearity as much as possible. Your light-like gauge is Lorentz-invariant but there are other Lorentz-invariant conditions and even with Lorentz-breaking conditions, the calculations may be made nicely and shown to lead to Lorentz-covariant physical predictions.

Comment: Maybe you could support us with a reference or an explicit proof, that the gauge choice $A^\mu A_\mu = 0$ is valid? I.e. that one can for any vector potential $A^\mu$ satisfying the (vacuum) Maxwell equations a scalar $\Lambda$ s.th. $A^\mu + \partial^\mu \Lambda$ is a null vector?

Comment: Yup. The gauge is called Dirac gauge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing - this immediately gives this cute invariant choice a little bit of authority LOL. But note that (picking one sign of the square root everywhere) this is just $A_0=+\sqrt{|\vec A|^2}$ which is similar enough to $A_0=0$. You just need to bring the 4-vector $A_\mu$ to the light cone  at every point. I think that I would find an existence proof but I am not motivated enough to do it right now. As far as I remember, I was never exposed to it or asked to do it in the past.